# cancel outputing in pdb in emacs

Tags: python

In python-mode, I invoke pdb on a python script by `M-x pdb script.py`. I then type `c` to run till a breakpoint, and hit the name of a big list. It keeps on printing the content of the list in the buffer for pdb, and how can I cancel the printing? 
C-c C-c doesn't work.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't know the answer to the question, but a process is normally stopped in its tracks with `delete-process` or `kill-process`.  See https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Deleting-Processes.html **and** http://stackoverflow.com/a/10628109/2112489 **and** http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Signals-to-Processes.html

Answer (score 1):

As lawlist commented, at this point the Python-process must be stopped. See also M-x list-processes. A brute-force method would kill the buffer.